# In Ubuntu 14.04 downloads are very slow

Tags: 14.04, download-speed

I know there are threads about this, but I haven't found how can I solve my problem, I use Ubuntu 14.04, and among all the issues I have with this new version, the biggest one is that downloads are going about 50KBps, when my connection  is 2Mbps.

I'm quite sure nobody is stealing me wifi(I check almost everyday).

Using windows 8 downloads are about 230KBps on the SAME downloads.

My connection is Wired and I'm totaly sure that my pc's hardware is not the problem.

If someone has anything to solve this issue, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: in firefox, you can enable pipelining and increase maxrequests. also as the other guy suggested, you can use a download manager. though personally, i don't think uget is any good. give flareget and firefox's downThemAll a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to setup repositories from where you can download software in maximum bandwidth.
Here is how:

Unity(DASH_board) > software and updates > Ubuntu Software > Download From > Other > Choose Best Server > OK > OK.

Reload cache and try again downloading software.

On the other hand, you can also use download manager in Ubuntu "uget". You can download it from Ubuntu software center.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've tried a little bit and by now, I think It worked, but I'll keep trying.